# What is the point of parenting mesh?

Tags: parent

[image]

Hi. I'am a beginner and studying a given file. I wonder what the point is having a mesh parent related others? just for convenience so that you can move all of them easily? why don't they manage via collection? is there any beneficial reason or situation for doing this for particular purpose?
I thought this feature is only used for rigging.

Comment: [Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy) is  a fundamental of many data structures.  You probably don't use  global gps coordinates for your current location. Rather a street a suburb, a town, a city, a country etc. Similarly for a model made up of parts a child's transform is inherited from a parent.  IMO better to learn fundamentals than question _the point of them_

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you. but what is the difference between learning fundamentals and question the point of them?

Comment: _What is the point of learning anything?_

Comment: What is the point of learning anything? is that your answer to my question? or are you asking me that question?

Comment: In this video https://youtu.be/Q6FS9sRJcDQ?t=26 the circuit board and all its components are parented to an empty and that empty is what is animated horizontally, that empty is then parented to another empty that is used as the pivot point. Made life very easy. Also the camera at this point for rotation https://youtu.be/Q6FS9sRJcDQ?t=48 is a simple "parent to circle" and then rotate the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenting provides an important convenience in organizing assemblies of objects - as mentioned in the commentary to your question.

But I guess the most important distinction between joining or grouping objects and parenting them is that, as far as transforms are concerned, the parent-child relationship is **one-way**. Children inherit the transformations of their parent - but a parent does not inherit the transformations of its children. This is vital to animation and rigging.

Consider a fairly simple animation of, say, the Earth orbiting the Sun, and the Moon orbiting the Earth (even without rotating at different speeds on their own axes) .. try it without parenting, and you'd soon be convinced of the need for it. There would be a lot of maths to do :)